# Цикл крутится только один раз

Tags: python, python-3.x

проблема в том, что цикл "for line in file.readlines()": - обрывается после одной попытки, пробовал file.read .readline .readlines

```
import os
import sys
import uu
import zipfile
from pathlib import Path
def get_subs(file_name):
    start = 'Sub'
    end = 'End'
    file = open(file_name, 'rb')
    out = open('Subs.txt', 'w')
    flag = False
    itog = ""
    for line in file:
        string = line.decode('ISO-8859-1')
        if string == start:
            itog = itog + "\t" + line
            flag = True

        if srting == end:
            itog = itog + "\t" + line
            flag = False

        if flag == True:
            itog = itog + "\t" + line
            out.write(itog)


def macro():
    cwd = os.getcwd()

    #doc_path = sys.argv[1]
    doc_path = "doc_file_clear.doc"
    os.rename(doc_path, "doc_file_clear.zip")
    path = os.path.abspath("doc_file_clear.zip")
    zip_archieve = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
    counter = 1

    for file in zip_archieve.namelist():
        if Path(file).suffix == '.bin':
            zip_archieve.extract(file, cwd)
            os.rename(file, str(counter) + ".text.bin")
            flag = True
            counter = counter + 1

    if flag == True:
        print('GOOD!', counter - 1, '-text finded!')
    else:
        print("Can't find! File is Clear")
    zip_archieve.close()
    path_ = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'word')
    os.rmdir(path_)
    os.rename(path, "doc_file_clear.doc")

    _path_ = os.path.abspath(str(counter - 1) + ".text.bin")
    return _path_
   
get_subs(macro())
```

file.bin выглядит так:
одна строчка в нем состоит из (d0cf 11e0 a1b1 1ae1 0000 0000 0000 0000)

```
d0cf 11e0 a1b1 1ae1 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000 0000 0000 0000 3e00 0300 feff 0900
0600 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000
0100 0000 0000 0000 0050 a444 0200 0000
0100 0000 feff ffff 0000 0000 0000 0000
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
fdff ffff 4000 0000 feff ffff 0400 0000
0500 0000 4500 0000 0700 0000 1e00 0000
0900 0000 0a00 0000 0b00 0000 0c00 0000
0d00 0000 0e00 0000 0f00 0000 1000 0000
1100 0000 1200 0000 1300 0000 1400 0000
1500 0000 1600 0000 1700 0000 1800 0000
1900 0000 1a00 0000 1b00 0000 1c00 0000
1d00 0000 0600 0000 1f00 0000 2000 0000
2100 0000 2200 0000 2300 0000 2400 0000
2500 0000 2600 0000 2700 0000 2800 0000
2900 0000 2a00 0000 2b00 0000 2c00 0000
2d00 0000 2e00 0000 2f00 0000 3000 0000
3100 0000 3200 0000 3300 0000 3400 0000
3500 0000 3600 0000 3700 0000 3800 0000
3900 0000 3a00 0000 3b00 0000 3c00 0000
3d00 0000 3e00 0000 3f00 0000 feff ffff
6500 0000 4200 0000 4300 0000 4400 0000
feff ffff 6400 0000 4f00 0000 4800 0000
4900 0000 4a00 0000 4b00 0000 4c00 0000
4d00 0000 4e00 0000 4100 0000 5000 0000
5100 0000 5200 0000 5300 0000 5c00 0000
5500 0000 5600 0000 5700 0000 5800 0000
5900 0000 5a00 0000 5b00 0000 4600 0000
5d00 0000 5e00 0000 5f00 0000 6000 0000
6100 0000 6200 0000 6300 0000 feff ffff
7600 0000 feff ffff 6700 0000 6800 0000
6900 0000 6a00 0000 6b00 0000 6c00 0000
feff ffff 6e00 0000 6f00 0000 7000 0000
7100 0000 7200 0000 7300 0000 7400 0000
7500 0000 6600 0000 7700 0000 feff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file.read()` - Считывает весь файл в строку

`file.readline()`  - Считывает только одну строку

`file.readlines()` - Считывает весь файл в массив (список)

**Что-то такое должно получиться:**

```
import re

flag = False
with open('txt.txt', 'r', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1') as file:

    for string in file.readlines():
        
        itog = ''

        if re.search(r'\bSub\b', string):
            if not re.search(r'\bEnd\b', string):
                itog = itog + "\t" + string
            flag = True

        if re.search(r'\bEnd\b', string):
            itog = itog + "\t" + string
            flag = False
            print(itog)

        if flag == True:
            if not re.search(r'\bSub\b', string):
                itog = itog + "\t" + string
            print(itog)
```

Comment: попробовал, как вы сказали, в отладчике цикл пробегает один раз (идет в начале, берет строку (закодированную) меняет ее кодировку, потом пробегает по if-ам и не попав ни в один - выходит из всей функции get_subs)

Comment: Я не вчитывался в код, какая у вас цель? Поменять кодировку файла? Если да, то можно сначала считать файл, а затем открыв его с ключом на запись (w) записать содержимое уже с новой кодировкой. Правда, не знаю насколько это рационально

Comment: файл (который открывается в цикле) из себя представляет .bin с буквами, находящимися в кодировке ISO-8859-1. мне необходимо открыть его, найти слово Sub и слово End и скопировать все, что находится между ними в отдельный файл

Comment: `Sub` и `End` всегда находятся в таком порядке, или может быть так, что `End` стоит раньше, чем `Sub`?

Comment: он ищет структуру которая представляет собой: Sub dhdbdh() .... End Sub, если по простому, функцию на visual basic. Она там есть, 100%, и не одна. Сам проверял в notepad-e

Comment: Отредактировал ответ. Попробуйте новый цикл

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open(file_name, 'rb'):
# ...
for line in file:
    string = line.decode('ISO-8859-1')
```

Во-первых - что-то я не вижу `readlines()`.

Во-вторых - не делайте так вот с `decode` потом. Открывайте сразу файл в нужной кодировке и в текстовом режиме, иначе у вас не факт что файл нормально поделится на строки. И да - лучше открывать через `with`, как написали в другом ответе, чтобы закрытие файла происходило автоматически.

```
with open(file_name, encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line ...
```

Скорее всего у вас `readlines` выдавал весь файл одной строкой из-за того, что файл был открыт в двоичном режиме.

Comment: к сожалению , после изменения способа открытия (добавления кодировки) - файл перестал открываться, файл из себя представляет .bin с буквами, находящимися в кодировке ISO-8859-1. мне необходимо открыть его найти слово Sub и слово End и скопировать все, что находится между ними в отдельный файл

Comment: @War_Never_Changes А, ну тогда всё-таки читайте в двоичном режиме и через file.read и смотрите побайтово файл. Хорошо бы файл куда-то приложить, так сложно без фактуры

Comment: прекриплю к вопросу